# vue v2 value inside object inside class property changed although not altered

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using vue v2 to create an SPA.
I declared an Offer class like this in the script section of my vue component:

```
class Offer {
       constructor(Tariff, TariffCopy, billing, at, fa, backs) {
       this.Tariff = Tariff;
       this.BaseTariff = TariffCopy;
    }

    changeSAC(p1, p2) {
       ...
       this.Tariff.provAufwand.SO = this.BaseTariff.provAufwand.SO + Number(p1);
    }
}
```

Tariff and TariffCopy are objects initialized from a custom class called Tariff also declared in the script section of the same component. Basically they contain the same values, but Tariff is open to value changes, while BaseTariff's values shall remain unchanged.

```
class Tariff{
    constructor(provAufwand) {
        this.provAufwand = provAufwand;
    }
}
```

where

```
provAufwand= {
    SO: 1,
    HO5: 2,
    HO10: 3,
    HO20: 4
}
```

When calling `Offer.changeSAC(p1,p2)` (p1 and p2 are bound to number inputs via `v-model="p1"` and `v-model="p2"`) the value of `this.BaseTariff.provAufwand.SO` is changed, too, although I never alter it in the code.
Why is that? Where in my code are they connected?

Comment: Did you declare `provAufwand` once and use the same variable when you created `Tarrif` and `TariffCopy` in `new Tariff(provAufwand)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you created your `Tariff` instances like these:

```
const provAufwand= {
    SO: 1,
    HO5: 2,
    HO10: 3,
    HO20: 4
};
const tariff = new Tariff(provAufwand);
const tariffCopy = new Tariff(provAufwand);
```

Then the reason why `BaseTariff` or `tariffCopy` is also changing when you changed  `tariff` is that they are referencing the same `provAufwand` object.

When you passed `provAufwand` to the `Tariff` constructor, the parameter that was passed was not the actual `value` of the object but the `reference` to the object.

> When you passed an `object` or an `array` to a function, then the argument
>   is **passed by reference**.

This means that changing the value of the object/array inside the function affect the value of the same object/array outside the function.

To solve it, you can use the [`spread syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) when passing `provAufwand` when creating a new `Tariff` object.

```
const provAufwand= {
    SO: 1,
    HO5: 2,
    HO10: 3,
    HO20: 4
};
const tarrif = new Tariff({...provAufwand});
const tarrifCopy = new Tariff({...provAufwand});
```

This ensures that you are passing completely different objects when creating your class instances.